# Tkinter freezes when looping through OHLC data

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I programmed an app in Tkinter and when I run it the ohlc plot is working properly but the tkinter window is freezing. I am a beginner of multiprocessing in Tkinter and any help is appreciated.

https://github.com/DataScientist2807/Tkinter/blob/master/SetupFrameWindowStockkApp_031_stackoverflow.py

#### edit: I attached the code below. The GUI is freezing. I do not know how to best solve this issue. Whether I use Multiprocessing or using the animate function in Matplotlib or any other solution.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Menu, ttk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import os
import pandas as pd
import json 
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from mplfinance.original_flavor import candlestick_ohlc
from datetime import datetime
import time
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import numpy as np
import threading
from multiprocessing import Process
import multiprocessing


def convert_ticks_to_ohlc(df, df_column, timeframe):
    data_frame = df[df_column].resample(timeframe).ohlc()
    return data_frame



valInterval = "5Min"
valCandles = 30
valValueSim = 0


class StockApp(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        Process(target=self.initiate_mastergrid()).start()
        Process(target=self.init_menuBar()).start()
        Process(target=self.initFrames()).start()
        Process(target=self.main_frame()).start()


    def initiate_mastergrid(self):
        # Configure the grid
        self.master.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=4)
        self.master.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.master.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.master.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1)


    def initialize_mainchart(self):
        self.figmain = plt.figure(figsize=(20,5), dpi=80)
        dataPlot2 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.figmain, master=self.mainFrame)
        self.am2 = plt.subplot2grid((4,5), (1,0), rowspan=2, colspan=5)
        self.am1 = plt.subplot2grid((4,5), (0,0), rowspan=1, colspan=5, facecolor="#F0F0F0", sharex=self.am2)
        self.am3 = plt.subplot2grid((4,5), (3,0), rowspan=1, colspan=5, sharex=self.am2)
        self.am2.yaxis.tick_right() # Price, Indicator and Volume Labels on the right
        self.am1.yaxis.tick_right() # Price, Indicator and Volume Labels on the right
        self.am3.yaxis.tick_right() # Price, Indicator and Volume Labels on the right

        plt.setp(self.am2.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
        plt.setp(self.am1.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
        plt.tight_layout(pad=0, w_pad=-1, h_pad=-1)

        plt.ion() # Necessary to animate plot
        dataPlot2.draw()
        dataPlot2.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)



    def load_data(self):
        global tick_data
        os.chdir("C:\\Trainings\\Python\\Tkinter\\StockApp\\SampleData")
        tick_data = pd.read_csv("EURUSD-2019_01_01.csv",
                        index_col=["time"], 
                        usecols=["time", "ask", "bid"],
                        parse_dates=["time"])



        print("Data has been loaded")


    def clear_axes(self, axes):
        axes.clear() # - Clear the chart


    def update_chart(self, candle_data):

        candlestick_ohlc(self.am2, candle_data, width=(15*0.5)/(24*60), 
                         colorup='#075105', 
                         colordown='#AF141A')

        for label in self.am2.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
            label.set_rotation(45)
        self.am2.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(10))
        self.am2.grid(True)
        plt.grid(False)
        plt.xlabel('Candle count')
        plt.ylabel('Price')
        plt.title('Candlestick chart simulation')
        plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.09, bottom=0.20, right=0.94, 
                            top=0.90, wspace=0.2, hspace=0)
        self.figmain.canvas.draw() # - Draw on the chart


    def candlestick_simulation(self, tick_data, time_frame, candle_window):

        candlestick_data = convert_ticks_to_ohlc(tick_data, 
                                                 "ask", 
                                                 "15Min").dropna()

        print("Converts tick to ohlc")


        candlestick_data = candlestick_data.reset_index()

        dvalues = candlestick_data[['open', 'high', 'low', 'close']].values.tolist()
        pdates = mdates.date2num(candlestick_data.time)
        ohlc = [[pdates[i]] + dvalues[i] for i in range(len(pdates))]

        print("Converted ohlc")

        self.ohlc_animate(ohlc)


        print("Start animation")

    def ohlc_animate(self, ohlclist):

        emptyOHLC = []

        for i in range(0, 20):

            valuesOHLC = ohlclist[i]

            emptyOHLC = emptyOHLC + [valuesOHLC]

            p_update = Process(target=self.update_chart(emptyOHLC))
            p_update.start()
            p_update.join()

            #self.update_chart(emptyOHLC)

            print("Sleep 3 seconds")

            time.sleep(3.0)

            self.clear_axes(self.am2)


    def start_simulation(self):

        Process(target=self.candlestick_simulation(tick_data, valInterval, valCandles)).start()
        print("Start Simulation")


    def main_frame(self):
        global dataB


        Process(target=self.initialize_mainchart()).start()
        print("Main Frame initialised")

        Process(target=self.load_data()).start()
        print(len(tick_data))


    def initFrames(self):


        self.mainFrame = Frame(self.master,bd=1, relief="sunken") #whatever
        self.mainFrame.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)

    def init_menuBar(self):

        menubar = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menubar)

        # Add menu items
        file_menu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)
        indicator_menu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        indicator_menu.add_command(label="EURUSD", command=lambda: self.start_simulation())
        file_menu.add_cascade(label="Interval", menu=indicator_menu)


def main():
    app = StockApp()
    app.master.title("Stock App 2020 by datascience2807@gmail.com")
    width_value = app.master.winfo_screenwidth()
    height_value = app.master.winfo_screenheight()
    app.master.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (width_value,height_value))
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    threading.Thread(target=main()).start()
```

Comment: I havent checked your code but possibly your not running the ui from a different thread?

Comment: Rather than ` threading.Thread(target=main()).start()`  have you tried ` threading.Thread(target=main).start()` edit: If you call main() it will start your tkinter loop right away, and your thread will never finish being constructed.

Comment: Please don't link to code on another site. Take the time to create a proper [mcve].

Comment: I tried 'threading.Thread(target=main).start()' but it is still freezing.

Answer (score 0):

The target parameter in the Thread constructor should be a callable. Instead are calling main() and passing the return value of main (which does not return of course because its running the tkinter event loop).

```
threading.Thread(target=main()).start()
```

I think you meant to do this:

```
threading.Thread(target=main).start()
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your post. Unfortunately the GUI is still freezing I added the code in my first posting.

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter itself is difficult to use with `multiprocessing` due to `mutliprocessing`'s reliance on `pickle` and the lack of ability to pickle a Tkinter app. This often results in errors when using class based functions with the `Process` command. Furthermore, `time.sleep` forces the whole of the tkinter thread to hang for, in your case, 3 seconds. This then stop the code from working and prevents you from being able to close the window in the mean time.

The answer to this problem is to utilize, `self.after` within your code. `self.after` allows for asynchronous code to be written for Tkinter applications and is often used as an example for how to build stopwatch applications.

I have made quite a few changes your code, by dropping both `threading` and `mutliprocessing` throughout the code and moving the necessary objects to `self.after`. I feel one of the reasons your code did hang rather a lot was also the fact you loaded the data on the creation of the main frame. Perhaps it would've been better to load this before the tkinter program starts (by placing it in the `main()` function), this will prevent that long hang at the start.

Now for updated code:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sun May 17 11:21:57 2020

@author: Marcel
"""

import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from mplfinance.original_flavor import candlestick_ohlc
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker


def convert_ticks_to_ohlc(df, df_column, timeframe):
    data_frame = df[df_column].resample(timeframe).ohlc()
    return data_frame


valInterval = "5Min"
valCandles = 30
valValueSim = 0


class StockApp(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initiate_mastergrid()
        self.init_menuBar()
        self.initFrames()
        self.main_frame()

    def initiate_mastergrid(self):
        # Configure the grid
        self.master.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=4)
        self.master.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.master.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.master.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1)

    def initialize_mainchart(self):
        self.figmain = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 5), dpi=80)
        dataPlot2 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.figmain, master=self.mainFrame)
        self.am2 = plt.subplot2grid((4, 5), (1, 0), rowspan=2, colspan=5)
        self.am1 = plt.subplot2grid(
            (4, 5), (0, 0), rowspan=1, colspan=5, facecolor="#F0F0F0", sharex=self.am2
        )
        self.am3 = plt.subplot2grid(
            (4, 5), (3, 0), rowspan=1, colspan=5, sharex=self.am2
        )
        self.am2.yaxis.tick_right()  # Price, Indicator and Volume Labels on the right
        self.am1.yaxis.tick_right()  # Price, Indicator and Volume Labels on the right
        self.am3.yaxis.tick_right()  # Price, Indicator and Volume Labels on the right

        plt.setp(self.am2.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
        plt.setp(self.am1.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
        plt.tight_layout(pad=0, w_pad=-1, h_pad=-1)

        plt.ion()  # Necessary to animate plot
        dataPlot2.draw()
        dataPlot2.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

    def load_data(self):
        global tick_data
        # os.chdir("C:\\Trainings\\Python\\Tkinter\\StockApp\\SampleData")
        tick_data = pd.read_csv(
            "EURUSD-2019_01_01.csv",
            index_col=["time"],
            usecols=["time", "ask", "bid"],
            parse_dates=["time"],
        )

        print("Data has been loaded")

    def clear_axes(self, axes):
        axes.clear()  # - Clear the chart

    def update_chart(self, candle_data):

        candlestick_ohlc(
            self.am2,
            candle_data,
            width=(15 * 0.5) / (24 * 60),
            colorup="#075105",
            colordown="#AF141A",
        )

        for label in self.am2.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
            label.set_rotation(45)
        self.am2.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(10))
        self.am2.grid(True)
        plt.grid(False)
        plt.xlabel("Candle count")
        plt.ylabel("Price")
        plt.title("Candlestick chart simulation")
        plt.subplots_adjust(
            left=0.09, bottom=0.20, right=0.94, top=0.90, wspace=0.2, hspace=0
        )
        self.figmain.canvas.draw()  # - Draw on the chart

    def candlestick_simulation(self, tick_data, time_frame, candle_window):

        candlestick_data = convert_ticks_to_ohlc(tick_data, "ask", "15Min").dropna()

        print("Converts tick to ohlc")

        candlestick_data = candlestick_data.reset_index()

        dvalues = candlestick_data[["open", "high", "low", "close"]].values.tolist()
        pdates = mdates.date2num(candlestick_data.time)
        ohlc = [[pdates[i]] + dvalues[i] for i in range(len(pdates))]

        print("Converted ohlc")

        self.ohlc_animate(ohlc)

        print("Start animation")

    def ohlc_animate(self, ohlclist):

        emptyOHLC = []

        for i in range(0, 20):

            valuesOHLC = ohlclist[i]

            emptyOHLC = emptyOHLC + [valuesOHLC]

            self.after(3000 * (i + 1), self.update_chart, emptyOHLC)

    def start_simulation(self):
        self.candlestick_simulation(tick_data, valInterval, valCandles)
        print("Start Simulation")

    def main_frame(self):
        self.initialize_mainchart()
        print("Main Frame initialised")

        self.load_data()
        print(len(tick_data))

    def initFrames(self):
        self.mainFrame = tk.Frame(self.master, bd=1, relief="sunken")  # whatever
        self.mainFrame.grid(
            row=1, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1
        )

    def init_menuBar(self):

        menubar = tk.Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menubar)

        # Add menu items
        file_menu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)
        indicator_menu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        indicator_menu.add_command(
            label="EURUSD", command=lambda: self.start_simulation()
        )
        file_menu.add_cascade(label="Interval", menu=indicator_menu)


def main():

    app = StockApp()
    app.master.title("Stock App 2020 by datascience2807@gmail.com")
    width_value = app.master.winfo_screenwidth()
    height_value = app.master.winfo_screenheight()
    app.master.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (width_value, height_value))
    app.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

#### The important line of code

```py
self.after(3000 * (i + 1), self.update_chart, emptyOHLC)
```

What this does is it builds a `queue` of chart updates and executes them 3 seconds after each other. So the first run of the loop would give, `3000` miliseconds and the second run would give `6000` milliseconds. This method results in a lot less hanging, in comparison to pausing the whole code with `time.sleep(1)`.

I hope this helps,

James

Comment: Hi James. Thank you for your post and your valuable hints and solutions. I was executing it and now it is running properly without freezing :)